# SuiteScript 2.0 TypeError Cannot call method "getValue" of undefined

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to get the values from two transaction body field using this code below .

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@param {Record} context.currentRecord
 */

define(['N/record'], 
function (msg) {
    
    function beforeSubmit(context) {
      try {

        var record = context.currentRecord;               

        var createdDate = record.getValue({
            fieldId: 'createddate'
        });

        var dataNecessidade = record.getValue({
            fieldId: 'custbodyek_data_nece_requ_po'
            
        });

        console.log(createdDate ,dataNecessidade);        

        }
        catch(ex){
        log.error(ex);
        }
    }
    return {
        beforeSubmit : beforeSubmit,
    
    };
});
```

The error raised is "*TypeError: Cannot call method "getValue" of undefined*"

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SuiteScript 2 each entry point has different parameters so you need to check those parameters on the Help or if you use an IDE like Eclipse, you will get that information when you create a new script, so for a *UserEvent* script and the *beforeSubmit* entry point, you will get something like this:

```
/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 * 
 * Task #5060 : calculate PO Spent Amount and Balance in realtime
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
```

and then you can see that the context parameter doesn't have a currentRecord property, instead, it has two other parameters that you can use *newRecord* or *oldRecord* so your code can be like this:

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@param {Record} context.currentRecord
 */

define(['N/record'], 
function (msg) {
    // are you aware that you are "injecting" the 'N/record' library into the 'msg' variable ???
    function beforeSubmit(context) {
      try {

        var record = context.newRecord;               

        var createdDate = record.getValue({
            fieldId: 'createddate'
        });

        var dataNecessidade = record.getValue({
            fieldId: 'custbodyek_data_nece_requ_po'
            
        });

        console.log(createdDate ,dataNecessidade);        

        }
        catch(ex){
        log.error(ex);
        }
    }
    return {
        beforeSubmit : beforeSubmit,
    
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi B Assem! Thanks for you contribution!
Actually, I'm using VS Code. Is there any way to get those parameters as the same way Eclipse IDE works? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @eklon I never used VS Code for Netsuite customisation so sorry I can't help you on that regard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `currentRecord` property on the `context` passed into a user event, hence the error message telling you that `record` is undefined. Review the docs for the `beforeSubmit` entry point to find the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

You try to write it like this, I always use this method to get the field value.

```
const bfRecord= context.newRecord;
const createdDate = bfRecord.getValue('createddate');
```